# occupancy grid implementation?

Tags: ros, slam, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is the most commonly used package in ROS for occupancy grid-based SLAM? I see slam_gmapping, octomap, voxel_grid

the jossum project also gives a very good demo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222097/occupancy-grid-implementation?/) by [teddyyyy123](https://answers.ros.org/users/25214/teddyyyy123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is probably [slam_gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping), but what is the purpose of this question? If you can clarify, we can help more in detail.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [teddyyyy123](https://answers.ros.org/users/25214/teddyyyy123/) on 2015-12-08**:
thanks, my goal is to pick an existing package which is the most mature and has the highest performance , so that I can just use it on my project without too much investigation and comparison by myself.